# OOP Python: Call child class method in Parent class method

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to understand what is the best way of letting Base Class X know that there will be a certain method in child class. Simplified example of my problem is:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, v1):
        self.v1
        # Maybe some standard definition here? 
        self.return_new_value = lambda x: 1
        
    def main(self):
        # or here maybe a assert that this function (return_new_value) exists?
        v2 = self.return_new_value()
        return self.v1 * v2
 
class X1(X):
    def return_new_value(self):
        return 5
    
class X2(X):
    def return_new_value(self):
        return 3
    
class X3(X):
    def return_new_value(self):
        return 2
    
    
x1 = X1(2).main()
x2 = X2(3).main()
x3 = X3(4).main()
```

Method `return_new_value` exists only in child classes and it's very specific but it's used in `main` for all instances of child class.
I might break here some OOP design patterns, just want to learn what is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that every derived class implemented/overridden a specific method you can declare `X` as abstract base class and decorate the required `return_new_value` method as [`abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class X(ABC):
    def __init__(self, v1):
        self.v1 = v1

    @abstractmethod
    def return_new_value(self):
        ...

    def main(self):
        v2 = self.return_new_value()
        return self.v1 * v2


class X1(X):
    def return_new_value(self):
        return 5


class X2(X):
    def return_new_value(self):
        return 3


class X3(X):
    def return_new_value(self):
        return 2

x1 = X1(2).main()
x2 = X2(3).main()
x3 = X3(4).main()
print(x1, x2, x3)
```

---

```
10 9 8
```

Comment: Can you give me 2 followups: 1) Can I use this decorator even when I Inherit X after more specific class like e.g. nn.Module or maybe inherit after two classes X(ABS, nn.Module); 2) what exactly this decorator "abstractmethod" is useful for?

Comment: @MateuszKonopelski, 1) you can mix other functionality to `X` with say `class X(nn.module,  metaclass=ABCMeta)`; 2) `abstractmethod` requires any child class to implement/override the underlined method, otherwise you'll an error like `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class X1 with abstract method return_new_value`